# How can my site detect mobile phones and switch visitors to a mobile Domain?

Tags: redirects, dns, 301-redirect, mobile, cpanel

My Question is that when user enter the website: `http://www.example.com` then they will just go to automatically to `http://www.example.mobi` how can i do this .. is their any technique behind that.

***Can i do this via cPanel etc?. Tutorial links are welcomed.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To redirect only mobile traffic to a mobile domain there are a few options:-

> **Simple**

Based on screen resolution (my favorite as it's fairly future proof)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "www.mobileurl.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

> **More granular control**

http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/ offers more complete control [with a free](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/mobile_device_detect.zip) script which handles redirection to a single place, or multiple places based on device (don't be fooled by all the buy buttons!)

```
require_once('[mobile_device_detect.php][4]');
mobile_device_detect(
  'http://iphone-url.com',
  'http://ipad-url.com',
  'http://android-url.com',
  'http://opera-mini-url.com',
  'http://blackberry-url.com',
  'http://palm-os-url.com',
  'http://mobile-url.com',
  'http://mobile-browsers-url.com',
  'http://desktop-url.com');
```

Allowing traffic from different devices to be sent to different urls.

> **Extremely granular control**

Other than that there are [device description databases](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pursueds#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&source=hp&q=device%20description%20databases&oq=device%20description%20databases&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=12&gs_upl=168064l168064l0l169048l1l1l0l0l0l0l55l55l1l1l0&gs_l=serp.12...168064l168064l0l169048l1l1l0l0l0l0l55l55l1l1l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=fc458632c6d138f5&biw=1920&bih=955) like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) which offer even more in depth control by providing a database that can be queried using device header information and traffic redirected accordingly...

Comment: is this helpful technique and i don't understood full, is this redirect the main domain. means if some one open in web-browser on the laptop/desktop computer then its not show .mobi domain but if some one enter to the mobile devices they have to redirect to the .mobi domain .. i just want that ...

Comment: @AppzVenture Oh, I see, you want to redirect ONLY mobile traffic to a mobile domain? Different kettle of fish, I'll update my answer

Comment: @AppzVenture updated with a few solutions for you...

Comment: Thanks thats really helpfull its solve lot of my time and investment. Thanks too much

Comment: @AppzVenture No worries.

Comment: Thats was awesome that soo much @toomanyairmiles i love your post today also i need today also its working great thanks so much i love this code

Answer (score 4):

The first method (`screen.width<=799`) is not reliable. On my Android, I get a screen width of 540 when the phone is being held upright (portrait view), but if I turn it on its side (landscape view), I get width=960. Better (maybe still not fully reliable) might be to bounce to mobile if *either* dimension is small:

```
if ((screen.width <= 699) || (screen.height <= 699)) {}
```