# Why would an IE8 in a desktop has a 'Tablet PC 2.0' in its user-agent string?

Tags: user-agent

I am just curious, why would a windows 7 desktop, installed with ie8, have Tablet PC 2.0 in its user agent string.

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2;
.NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media
Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0) Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE
8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; Tablet
PC 2.0)
```

Is this a feature in Windows 7, how can I turn this off in IE8?
Other browsers on the same computer don't have such string in the user-agent string they send.

As a result, one of our web application confuses this particular **desktop** client as a mobile (because of the tablet), hence returns the mobile version of our website to it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks to me like a Media Center PC with the [tablet edition](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/tablet-pc) of Windows 7 or Windows 2008 Server R2 installed (Both Identify as NT 6.1). [Hardware like this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/10-2-Windows-Tablet-PC-Processor/dp/B004D6R9T2) shows up with a similar string.

Take a look at [User Agent Strings](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/msie-history.html) for more help.

Personally I avoid using browser strings to select for tablet and mobile, its much more practical to use [screen resolution](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/detecting-and-redirecting-mobile-users/) and you're less likely to have fragmentation issues with the wide array of android tablets, phone and tablet/phones. My answer [to this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27244/switch-to-mobile-domain-automatically/27245#27245) covers the subject in more detail.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "domain.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you're right, thanks for your interesting suggestion. may i ask, did it really work for you like most of the time? :)

Comment: @ultrajohn it does, we just did exactly this at work on a mobile site for barclaycard - testing indicates we were successful 95% of the time. What kind of app are you developing?

Answer (score 3):

Browser manufacturers like to cram unecessary information into their user-agent strings for a variety of reasons. Originally it was to fool browser sniffers that were excluding IE from their website (that's why you see Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; in IE's user-agent). It looks like Microsoft is cramming everything IE8 can be used with into its user-agent which isn't particularly useful, and in this case, problematic.

You [can change your user-agent](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18450/change-the-user-agent-string-in-internet-explorer-8/) if you want but that won't change the fact that every other IE8 user will get the mobile version of your site. A better solution would be to improve the browser sniffer you're using and account for this in it. Or better yet, use a [responsive design](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=responsive%20design) instead.